# Single attribute value XML extract from SQL Server with xpath

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have the following XML that is stored in a xml column in a SQL Server 2012 table.

```
<Values>
  <V ID="MyValue1" Value="True" />
  <V ID="MyValue2" Value="False" />
</Values>
```

I am trying to get the `Value` from the node with the ID of "MyValue1" as a boolean from the XML. After a bit of searching and some SQL xml errors, I ended up with this:

```
SELECT ID, [Values],
  [Values].value('data(/Values/V[@ID="MyValue1"]/@Value)[1]', 'bit') AS MyBool
FROM [MyXmlValues]
```

This seems a bit nuts. Is there not a simpler way (e.g. without the data part) to query a single value via XPath?

Most of the questions and examples on StackOverflow use [1] to indicate the node but I can't be sure that my node is first which is to be expected in XML.

Comment: No, there's no "shortcut" or anything to do this - this **is** the way to "reach into" a XML structure and extract a single node's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `data()`. You can use

```
(/Values/V[@ID="MyValue2"]/@Value)[1]'
```

if you expect more nodes to have the ID you search for and want the first attribute value of them (i.e. the value of the attribute from the first node that has this attribute or

```
(/Values/V[@ID="MyValue2"])[1]/@Value'
```

if you want to chose the first node that has the ID and get its attribute value, regardless if it is set or not.

If only one node can have the ID, which seems reasonable, there is no difference.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8a770b07bf19f4d47995422209bb788)